# jQuery, fadeToggle, and list-items

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

OK, so.  I'm trying to create a dropdown menu of sorts using fadeToggle().

http://westrock.juggernautwebsites.com/ is where the site is currently located.

As you can see, when a user selects 'Properties', the fadeToggle occurs.  However, after the dropdown occurs, and a user wants to select a li from the properties dropdown, they are unable to (I know I have return false; set, but that was supposed to be for the original ul, no?)

As well, when the child items are displaying, if you hover over About, the :hover effect displays on the Properties child li.

I'm boggled.  Any help, greatly appreciated.

```
$('#menu-item-13').click(function() {
    $(this).children('ul').fadeToggle({
        duration: 200
    });
    return false;
});
```

*EDIT
I feel like I need to restrict the css and jQuery from affecting children list-items and a, but I don't know how to do this.  I thought children only went one level down the DOM, and since I selected 'ul', the function wouldn't affect list-items...

Comment: When I select 'Properties' nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's help!  Here's what I eventually ended up using.

```
$('#primary li').hover(function() {
    $(this).children('ul').fadeToggle({
        duration: 200
    });
});
    $('menu-item-54').click(function() {
    return false;
});
```

What I was trying to accomplish upon hover (or click), the subnav would expand open.

Answer (score 1):

Your example doesn't work at all for me, but if I'm understanding you correctly, you want the child `ul` to not be affected by the click handler attached to the parent.  You can do this:

```
$('#menu-item-13 > ul').click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();

   // ... do your thing
});
```

This basically stops the click on the `ul` from bubbling up to the parent `#menu-item-13`.  Because of this, the `fadeToggle` will also not trigger from the click on the ul, so if that is still needed you will have to add it to the `ul`'s click.

Comment: Sorry, I must have been working on it or something at the time.  I added the e.stopPropagation, but I can't trigger the fadeToggle by clicking on Properties.

Comment: `$('#primary li a').click(function(e) {
 $(this).next().fadeToggle({
  duration: 200
 });
 return false;
});`  does basically what I want, however, the return false; disables all the anchors in the nav, where I only want to disable links that have children (i.e. dropdown levels)

Comment: You seem to already have individual classes on the items which distinguish this, so why not use that?   `.menu-item-type-custom`